# Why sqrt(1-4*pow(X,2)) is showing math domain error, when X is less than 0.5?

Tags: python, abaqus, analytical

I tried to implement Hertz distribution load on a soil domain. The expression is sqrt(1-4*pow(X,2)) where X is less than 0.5. I get math domain error when i try in analytical field using expressions in ABAQUS. How to solve this problem.

Comment: you will try to caculate the quare root of a negative number then... you can use [`cmath.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt) in that case to get the complex result(s).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As mentioned above, my X has a value not more than 0.5. And also in ABAQUS expression field I couldnt use "cmath.sqrt".

Comment: I don't know ABAQUS, but maybe you have to explicitely restrict the domain of X to < 0.5 (and > -0.5 ) for the analytical stuff to work? A quick glance at the ABAQUS manual revealed something called "boundary conditions", have a look at that.

Comment: As far as I know, boundary conditions are given for a different reason.